# Is it still possible to get hat drops

Tags: team-fortress-2

I was just playing a pub server in TF2 and somebody in chat said they got a hat drop. Are they legit? Just wondering.

Answer (score 4):

It is still possible to get hat drops.

What they're referring to is the period of about a year from early 2015 to early 2016 where no random hat drops were happening.

Valve finally fixed that a few months ago.

Comment: Wait, what? No hat drops for a _year_? I had no idea!

Comment: @RavenDreamer It's been discussed on both the hlds server mailing list and Reddit.  I can't pin down the exact dates, though... Valve doesn't release that information.  Having said that, since Valve's API tracks how a player got an item and when it was originally created, a site like backpack.tf probably has this data somewhere on its site.